# Store password in Android Keystore using biometric API

Tags: android, kotlin, android-keystore

I want to store `password` in Android Key-store just confused where it stores actually the password is it in `Sharedpreference` or `File`

this is the code i tried so far

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.security.KeyStore
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator
import javax.crypto.SecretKey
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val KEY_ALIAS = "my_secure_key"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
        keyStore.load(null)

        val secretKey = if (keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)) {
            keyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null) as SecretKey
        } else {
            val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore"
            )

            val keyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                KEY_ALIAS,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
            )
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true) // Requires biometric authentication
                .build()

            keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec)
            keyGenerator.generateKey()
        }

        val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(
            this,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                    super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                    val cipher = result.cryptoObject?.cipher
                    if (cipher != null) {
                        val encryptedUsername = cipher.doFinal("my_username".toByteArray())
                        val encryptedPassword = cipher.doFinal("my_password".toByteArray())

                        // Store encryptedUsername and encryptedPassword as needed
                    }
                }

                override fun onAuthenticationError(
                    errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence
                ) {
                    super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                    // Handle authentication errors
                }

                override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                    super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                    // Handle authentication failures
                }
            }
        )

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(
            KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                    + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM + "/"
                    + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE
        )

        val secretKeyEntry = keyStore.getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, null) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry
        val secretKey = secretKeyEntry.secretKey

        val gcmSpec = GCMParameterSpec.Builder()
            .setKeySize(256)
            .setNonce(ByteArray(12)) // You need to generate a random nonce for each encryption
            .build()

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gcmSpec)

        val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Authenticate to access credentials")
            .setSubtitle("Using your biometric")
            .setDescription("Authenticate using your fingerprint to access your credentials.")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
            .build()

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo, BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(cipher))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android Keystore is a secure hardware-backed storage on Android devices specifically designed for cryptographic keys. It's not intended for storing plain text passwords directly.

Comment: can you share one example how to implement